# How are Dataflow bundles created after GroupBy/Combine?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**Setup:**

read from pubsub -> window of 30s -> group by user -> combine -> write to cloud datastore

**Problem:**

I'm seeing DataStoreIO writer errors as objects with similar keys are present in the same transaction.

**Question:**

1. I want to understand how my pipeline combines results into bundles after a group by/combine operation. I would expect the bundle to be created for every window after the combine. But apparently, a bundle can contain more than 2 occurrences of the same user?
2. Can re-execution (retries) of bundles cause this behavior?
3. Is this bundling dependent of the runner?
4. Is deduplication an option? if so, how would I best approach that?

Note that I'm not looking for a replacement for the datastore writer at the end of the pipeline, I already know that we can use a different strategy. I'm merely trying to understand how the bundling happens.

Comment: ah this is a very good question. TBH I don't know, but I'll do my best to get someone who does here.

Comment: Much appreciated @pablo ! :)

Comment: sorry for the delay. Will try to get some5thing tomorrow!

Comment: okay I went asking around. I hope the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers to your question. One is specific to your use case, and the other is in general about bundling / windowing in streaming.

---

**Specific to your pipeline**

I am assuming that the 'key' for Datastore is the User ID? In that case, if you have events from the same user in more than one window, your `GroupByKey` or `Combine` operations will have one separate element for every pair of user+window.

So the question is: What are you trying to insert into datastore?

- An individual user's resulting aggregate *over all time*? In that case, you'd need to use a Global Window.
- A user's resulting aggregate for every 30 seconds in time? Then you need to use the window as part of the key you use to insert to datastore. Does that help / make sense?

Happy to help you design your pipeline to do what you want. Chat with me in the comments or via SO chat.

---

**The larger question about bundling of data**

Bundling strategies will vary by runner. In Dataflow, you should consider the following two factors:

- Every worker is assigned a key range. Elements for the same key will be processed by the same worker.
- Windows belong to single elements; but **a bundle may contain elements from multiple windows**. As an example, if the *data freshness* metric makes a big jump*, a number of windows may be triggered - and elements **of the same key** in **different windows** would be processed **in the same bundle**.

---

*-  when can Data freshness jump suddenly? A stream with a single element with a very old timestamp, and that is very slow to process may hold the watermark for a long time. Once this element is processed, the watermark may jump a lot, to the next oldest element ([Check out this lecture on watermarks ; )](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWxSLmkWPm4)).